# canvas arc y-axis overflow

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to draw an arc within a canvas and i want to make that arc to fill the canvas.

i tried to make the arc half canvas's size and i works perfectly but when i increase the radius to be same width as the canvas i find an error...as for arc width its good but for the height it increases alot, disappears and i feel like radius is doubling the y-axis.

and when i check it in jsFiddle it works perfectly...maybe i have to do with some css or something?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var counterClockwise = false;
var x = canvas.width /2;
var y = canvas.height /2;

context.beginPath();
context.arc(x, y, x-9, 0, 2*Math.PI);
context.stroke();
```

and this the html body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css" />
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas2" style="width:207px;height:207px"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the width and height on the canvas element itself, not in CSS:

```
canvas.width=207;
canvas.height=207;
```

Setting width and height in css will distort your drawings (as you've discovered).

Also, when you draw an arc which you intend to be a circle, be sure to call context.closePath();

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/adGfS/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas2");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  canvas.width=207;
  canvas.height=207;

  var x = canvas2.width /2;
  var y = canvas2.height /2;

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, x-9, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  context.closePath();
  context.stroke();

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```